# The activity is not responding

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-3.0

I have been working on developing an application which needed login and signup screen. My register activity is not working properly.

The application is unable to take user from the start screen to the register activity, first the error arose of absence of intent filter then I included the intent filter in the manifest file but it seems like my app is ignoring the register activity.

I am attaching both manifest file and the activity code please have a look.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use images to share code, use code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As images are suggesting there are two `LAUNCHER` Activities in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file, so you will have to make one of them as `DEFAULT` `category`.

Put this line to your `intent-filter` of one `Activity`

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

instead of

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define registeractivity like login activity , remove the intentfilter & it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: but if I remove the intent filter then an error pops us showing that intent filter missing

Comment: you have intent filter in main activity ?